# Not Found when rewriting URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

So I have an `article.php` and what I'm trying to do is instead of `article.php?id=1`. I'm trying to do `article/1`. So here's what I'm doing

```
RewriteRule ^/article/([0-9]+)\.php /article.php?id=$1
```

All I get with this is

```
The requested URL /article/.php was not found on this server.
```

I think this has to do with the rest of my rewriting. Here's all the code I got

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/article/([0-9]+)\.php /article.php?id=$1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When using rewriting in .htaccess context, the path _never_ starts with a slash, because that has been stripped off at that point already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1
```

Instead of what you have?

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Still getting. `The requested URL /article/.php was not found on this server.` I think it's an issue wit the last part `article.php?id=$1`

Comment: No that bit should be fine as far as i can tell. So you removed your `RewriteRule ^/article/([0-9]+)\.php /article.php?id=$1` and replaced it with mine yeah? What are you typing in the address bar?

Comment: Yes I did. I also restarted the server just in case. I'm going to `http://localhost/article/10`

Comment: Try replacing your htaccess stuff with what i just put in the edit :)

Comment: The issue with what you just did is it messes up the rest of the site. Since I got rid of the `.php` early on.... Any work arounds?

Comment: Just trial and error at the moment. So .htaccess is is in the root of the site yeah?

Comment: Yep, it's in the root

Comment: No problem mate, glad it's all sorted :)